# Render result does not show up in compositing?

Tags: transparency, compositing-nodes

I have a weird issue when trying to get a smoke simulation with a transparent backround (transparent film is on).

**1.** One is that i don't get the show render layer option in the compositing nodes, as an option —— image editor the image is set to render result but it does not appear in render layer node

**2.** Another weird thing is that the blue smoke has correct alpha in the compositor, but when I save it as a PNG it's just a white screen and when i take it from there to Lightworks, it recognises the smoke but it only appears as a white cloud, without color and without alpha.

I have managed to get transparent background with solid objects to appear, but here I'm facing this problem with the render result missing and that I only seem to get some layers out of the image, but it seems allright in the
render results wiew in the image editor?

[image]

Comment: PNG is a fucked format and doesn’t encode alpha correctly. Never use it. Many answers here worth searching, as this is a duplicate.

Comment: I use PNG as it´s seem´s to support alpha in lightworks . I now tryed similar settings with simpler smoke settings, it can be that that some complexity in the settings caused these problems. try now to move on by more simple settings in compositing and smoke simulation in a hope , it will work out better. I have used PNG with alpha and it does not always have these problems.

Comment: i got it to work with less complex settings, probaply something made the process go out of order and created an error. If moderators want to close the case im fine with that. or want to leave it as an example that´s fine too.

Comment: PNG is a busted format. It really is. Avoid it.

Comment: It might be ... Eny succestions of a format that would work in lightworks too ?